# library not found for libstdc++.6.0.9 not found xcode 11.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, libstdc++

As this library is deprecated 5 years ago, the workaround is followed in this URL http://orenjiapp.com/2018/08/22/xcode-10-ios-12-does-not-contain-libstdc6-0-9/ 
"Indeed this workaround has worked to build the project successfully, but I don't want to use this temporary solution if I remove that libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd and trying to build the project using libc++.1.tbd and throwing errors as shown below".
"Does anyone know what is the actual solution for this scenario?"

"Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree, std::_Select1st >, std::less..."
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
The Errors which are currently facing as follows

"Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::__throw_length_error(char const*)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::allocator::allocator()

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::_List_node_base::unhook()

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::string::compare(std::string const&) const

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::string::operator=(char const*)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::allocator::~allocator()

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::string::operator=(std::string const&)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::string const&)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string()

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::string::length() const

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()

Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: std::string::c_str() const"

Comment: Solution is to update your libs/dependencies and not depend on this one, but others available.

Comment: How do we get to know that which libs/dependencies depend on this libstdc++ when this kind of error it gives?
"std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from: std::_Rb_tree, std::_Select1st >, std::less".
Can you tell me some more info so that I can get the root cause and remove those dependent libs/dependencies used in the project.

Comment: Are the libraries you use built from source or are you using a binary-only distribution from some supplier?  If the former you need to update them to build using the `libc++` runtime library instead of `libstdc++`.  If the latter then you need to get them to update their product or find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue try to follow below steps:

- Clone https://github.com/Kila2/libstdc-.6.0.9.tbd
- Copy two file: libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd and libstdc++.6.tbd
  to path
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib
  and
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
  (Change name Xcode.app to name version xcode)
- Add the copied library (libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd) and (libstdc++.6.tbd) to “Build Phase-> Link libraries” Path of Xcode project.
- Clean xcode and rebuild it